# What does the abbreviation »ankl« mean in German?

Tags: abbreviation

After finishing reading an article today in *Süddeutsche Zeitung*, I scrolled down the page a bit and saw the following text:

> ©SZ vom 31.08.2018/ankl

What does *ankl* mean? I could not find the abbreviation in any of the online dictionaries I use.

Here is a screenshot of the page with the text (circled at the bottom):
[image]

Comment: +1 for providing the context.

Answer (score 14):

Heißer Tipp: **An**ne **Kl**einmann, SZ-Redakteurin im Newsdesk-Team (https://www.sueddeutsche.de/tools/impressum).

(It is common for German newspapers to tag simple, factual articles with the initials of the author(s), along with the abbreviations of news agencies whose material was used. E.g., in the SZ's archive, you can find even rather long strings of contributors like "SZ.de/ap/dpa/eca/ankl", which typically means that eca (presumably **E**va **Ca**sper, also of the newsdesk team) and ankl mashed a few wire reports from AP and DPA for sueddeutsche.de.)

Answer (score 9):

`ankl` isn't an abbreviation in German. But you find short signatures at the end of articles. These are usually an abbreviated form of the authors name. The slash is used to indicate this form of signatures.